# Regex doesn't working properly

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a small routing system that allows me to define the structural logic of the URLs on my Rest API:

```
$listUri = "transaction /.+";
$uri = isset($_REQUEST['uri'])? $_REQUEST['uri']: '/'; //Transaction/19.02.2016

if(preg_match ("#$#^$listUri$#",$ uri)
{
    echo "done!";
}
```

As you can see `$listUri` contains all mapped url (those acceptable by the system), so I can iterate through of it and try to match against the url. The variable `$uri` take the current url in the browser, now I use a simple regular expression to make the match with the url and the example shown above everything works properly. However, we may experience a situation like this:

```
$listUri = "transaction/.+";
$uri = isset ($_REQUEST['uri'])? $_REQUEST ['uri']: '/'; //Transaction/19.02.2016/user

if(preg_match("#$#^$listUri$#", $ uri))
{
    echo "done!";
}
```

The variable `$listUri` contains "/.+", so the url mapped can only accept one parameter after "transaction" (as which has already been shown in the first example). This time the variable `$uri` contains a wrong request, as shown in the first example in fact the request is correct, but this time there is a `user` after parameter because it's wrong. Why is it wrong? 'Cause in `$listUri` the url is mapped as "transaction/.+", this means that if I place. "+/user" echo shouldn't be printed.
I should do in order to achieve a regular expression that allows me to recognize if there are ".+" And if they match the current url. Obviously the url is dynamic so you have to create a pattern that works for all.

**In essence (with an example):**

```
$listUri => "transaction /.+"
```

*operation*

```
$uri => "transaction/19.02.2016/" (corrected)
$uri => "transaction/19.02.2016/user/test/dd" (wrong - mapping only accepts transaction/.+ other parameters mmust not be taken into account)"
```

I don't know if I was clear. I hope someone help me to build the regex, I'm not very good with it.

**UPDATE** `$listUri` content

`$listUri` contains a list of mapped uri, so the could contain this:

- transaction/.+
- user/.+
- transaction/example/.+
- football/.+

and so on..

Comment: The regex seems wrong: the first and last character of the regex needs to be the same, for example `preg_match( "#^$listUri$#", $uri )`. Also, `.` in a regexp means "any character" and `+` means "match as many as you can". So the `.+` will match everything after `transaction/`.

Comment: @Kenney I fix the wrong typo.. anyway the problem is not solved. So I should use another symbol?

Comment: *...yes* - `if(preg_match("~$#^$listUri$~", $ uri))` or `if(preg_match("~#$#^$listUri$#~", $ uri))` depending on what you want to check for.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think that will work. The `$` should be the ending of the string. The `^` should be the start. This question is too confusing for me to jump into though.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure I understand the question clearly, but I think you are looking for `preg_match( '@^transaction/[^/]+$@' )` - the `[^/]` matches any character except `/`, the `+` requires 1 or more characters; `^` means start of string, `$` means end of string.

Comment: @chris85 Why confused? I can clarify your doubts? Tell me what isn't clear. Anyway @Kennedy as I said in the question the url is dynamic. So you must think in general, not just for "transaction", at the place of transaction there is `$listUri` in a generic url.

Comment: Your code samples differ, that regex as written should be throwing errors. It seems like the question could just be the `In essence` bit. Should there be a space between `transaction` and the `/`?

Comment: @chris85 a space? Nope, it's a simple URI without any space. If the user put an url that match with the uri the echo is printed also it will be printed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work:

`"^[^/]+\/[^/]+\/?$/"`

[Example](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eHK)

- Match at least one character (that isn't `/`) but as many as possible in the beginning of the string, followed by a slash
- `[^/]*` Match as many characters as possible that isn't a slash
- `\/?$` Last character of string should be an optional slash

(Just noticed this answer contains the word "slash" an awful lot)

Comment: This works only for "transaction"? 'cause as I said in the question the url mapped is dynamic, this mean that you need to thnk a general solution for fix the problem not only for transaction.. That's just an example .

Comment: @Dillinger Edited it, now it will work for any word (updated example too)

Comment: okay, but where the variable `$listUri` should be placed in preg_match? The variable `$listUri` contains the uri to match against the current `$uri`

Comment: @Dillinger Sorry I don't understand that part of the question.  `$listUri` contains all acceptable beginnings of the string? "transaction" etc?

Comment: `listUri` It contains all mapped url. By this I mean that you have to think that there is a list of uri to compare, I've updated the question so as to make you understand better.

Comment: If you iterate the list you can concatenate them using `|` (or in regex), so for example you'd get: `^(?:transaction|whatever)\/[^/]+\/?$`. So you could build up the regex like that, the `(?:)` is a group that you don't include in the matches. This would mean you need to make your list contain only `transaction` and not `transaction/.*` of course

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104045/discussion-between-dillinger-and-alexander-derck).